# How to generate dates between two dates convert it to week nbr, add it to an existing dataframe and map it to user id

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I was hoping if anyone could help me with this use-case:

I want to generate dates between two dates and then tag each date with week number, then add both new generated dates and week number as new columns to the original dataframe and map it to user id.

this is the existing dataframe:

| user_id | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-14 | 2022-03-14 |
| 3 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-02-05 |
| 4 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-02-25 |

generating dates between start and end date and tag date with wk number

| user_id | date | week_nbr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-07 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-08 | w2 |

Finally map the generated wk and dates back to the original table using user_id:

| user_id | start_dt | end_dt | date | week_nbr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-01 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-02 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-03 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-04 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-05 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-06 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-07 | w1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-08 | w2 |

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should give you what you are looking for:

```
(df.assign(
    date = [pd.date_range(s,e) for s,e in zip(df['start_dt'],df['end_dt'])])
    .explode('date')
    .assign(week_nbr = lambda x: np.char.add('w',((np.arange(len(x))//7)+1).astype(str))))
```

Old answer:

```
(df.assign(
    date = [pd.date_range(i,j) for i,j in zip(df['start_dt'],df['end_dt'])]).explode('date')
 .assign(week_nbr = lambda x: x.groupby('user_id')['date']
         .diff()
         .dt.days
         .cumsum()
         .floordiv(7)
         .add(1,fill_value=0)
         .astype(int)
         .map('w{}'.format))
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output: (top 5 rows)

```
     user_id   start_dt     end_dt       date week_nbr
0          1 2022-01-01 2022-02-01 2022-01-01       w1
1          1 2022-01-01 2022-02-01 2022-01-02       w1
2          1 2022-01-01 2022-02-01 2022-01-03       w1
3          1 2022-01-01 2022-02-01 2022-01-04       w1
4          1 2022-01-01 2022-02-01 2022-01-05       w1
```

Comment: hi there, the dataset that I'm dealing with is huge with more than 100K user_id with various start-end dates I realized it is not feasible to generate dates for every single user. Is there a way to JUST generate week_nbr based on range between start-end date without having to create a 'date' column?